# cannot upgrade current target for ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, universal

i try to upgrade my old existing app to make it a universal application for iphone and ipad.
i clicked on my target and tryed to select "upgrade current target for ipad", but i cannot click it, because its not clickable.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80699/Bildschirmfoto%202010-05-05%20um%2018.21.30.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80699/Bildschirmfoto%202010-05-05%20um%2018.21.30.png)

my project settings are:

- The Base SDK is set to iPhone Device 3.2
- The iPhone OS Deployment Target is set to iPhone OS 3.1
- The Targeted Device Family is set to iPhone/iPad

are there any other things i have to pay attention?

please help, to get my application upgraded.

Comment: What do you have selected in the project explorer window when you open the menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Targeted Device Family should be set to 'Iphone' for this option to be available, otherwise Xcode thinks its already targets iPad. (i.e change it from 'iPhone/iPad' to 'iPhone').

Comment: yeah that worked. first it doesnt work, but opening and closing the target info again, helped (whysoever). thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open your project in Xcode, in the left "Groups & Files" pannel find the "Targets" group. Open it up and highlight your target (it will be the name of your app). Now click the Project menu, voila!! The "Upgrade Current Target for iPad" option is selectable.

I fell for that one too, shame the documentation isn't clearer and there aren't 100 things called target!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have Xcode 3.2.2 prerelease and i can not find the "Upgrade Current Target for iPad" option under my project menu.

Is this due to Xcode version??

Comment: This should be posted as a separate question.  Just click the "Ask Question" button at the top right of the page.